# I want to Customise the Message Shown when Form Submitted in html. How to to do it?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have built a Send Email from a Static HTML Form using Google Apps Mail. The problem is that when I submit the form, I see a confirmation message that it was sent like:

> {"result":"success","data":"{\"firstname\":[\"Abhay\"]}"}

I want to remove that and besides that I want a clean text after a form submission e.g. "Thanks for submitting". Please correct my code to remove this output.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title> contact form </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <form id="gform" method="POST" 
    action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwlSM9z9ELHa1- 
    X6C_srRrB0j7FUlGgevJw7w7M/exec" >
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." 
    required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Put  here custom message')"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

    <div style="display: none;" id="thankyou_message">
    <h2> <em>Thanks</em>xfn</h2>
    </div>

    <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script- 
    without-server/master/form-submission-handler.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Instead of using a 3rd party script, have you tried developing your own Google Apps Script to manage the mailing side of this?

Comment: No @ross, i have not! and thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax request instead of submitting the from directly.

```
 <form id="gform" onsubmit="return postMessage()">
```

In below

```
<script>
    function PostMessage() {
        var form = document.getElementById('gform')

        fetch('"https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwlSM9z9ELHa1- 
       X6C_srRrB0j7FUlGgevJw7w7M/exec', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(a)).toString()
     }).then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
    .then(function(data){
        if(data.result == "success") {
            document.getElementById('thankyou_message').style.display = 'block';
        }
     });
     return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Very very thanks Rahul for the help. You have solved my half of the problem to not display that shitty message like: {"result":"success","data":"{\"firstname\":[\"Abhay\"]}"} But i want a code that when user submits his name the page shows thank you message.

Comment: Andrew when you were doing direct form post, it navigated(new page, url will change)  to (https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwlSM9z9ELHa1-X6C_srRrB0j7FUlGgevJw7w7M/exec), hence you saw the raw json on the page. But when using fetch, you will still be on the  same page, and `document.getElementById('thankyou_message').style.display = 'block';` line will show thank you message.